# Add list of directories to Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have an environment variable called $MYCLASSPATH that contains a set of directories that contain JARS. An example of my environment variable could be the following:

```
/project1/jars/:/project2/jars:/project3/jars
```

I also have a maven project that contains some external dependencies that are defined in the pom.xml. However, I want to include all the directories listed in the above environment variable in Maven since some JARS are required for the compilation.

Without Maven I could do this:

```
javac -cp "$MYCLASSPATH" path/to/my/java_file
```

How can I add all these directories to Maven?

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to crowne's answer, once you know the coordinates the external dependencies would have to be added to your local maven repository using `mvn install:install-file`

For example

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path_to_your_jar -DgroupId=X -DartifactId=X -Dversion=X -Dpackaging=jar
```

Your POM can then contain these dependencies in the same way normal dependencies are declared eg.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>X</groupId>
    <artifactId>X</artifactId>
    <version>X</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each jar should be identified by a specific set of maven coordinates
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates

This lets us know which version of the jar the project is dependent on and where to get it from in the maven repository.

It also allows the project to be built correctly from another computer with a different set of environment variables.

So you should define your dependencies in your pom using the correct maven coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! However, in my case this list of jars is very large. Could it be automatically given somehow? Also, in my case I don't know exactly what jars are required.

Comment: Defining a correct POM, is meant to solve the issue of "I don't know exactly what jars are required". Once it is correctly defined then the next person does not need to guess. I've found that with maven (and many other tools) you either use it the way it was intended to be used or swim against the stream and suffer with work-arounds and kludges.